Weird rig deform after outline effect
I followed this video to get an outline effect for my materials.
I've rigged my model and the outline effect deforms weirdly?
 
I just selected all of my meshes and parented with automatic weights, the wrist band also seems to not have parented correctly and I can't get it to.

Automatic weights don't work with inverted normals. Have you checked the normals?

hey thanks! Didn't even think about that
